# Filling Sierpinski triangle

Tags: matlab

I wish to create filled Sierpinski triangles. Instead my code produces a Sierpinski triangle with filled background. In other terms, how can I inverse the colors? See code  below:

```
function out = sierpinski(a, b, c, n)
M1 = (a+b)/2;
M2 = (b+c)/2;
M3 = (a+c)/2;
k = [M1(1), M2(1), M3(1)];
m = [M1(2), M2(2), M3(2)];
if n==0
    out.x=[a(1), b(1), c(1)];
    out.y=[a(2), b(2), c(2)];
    patch(out.x,out.y,'r')  % choosing the color red in this case
else
    s1 = sierpinski(a,M1,M3,n-1);
    s2 = sierpinski(M1,b,M2,n-1);
    s3 = sierpinski(M3,M2,c,n-1);
    out = [s1 s2 s3];
end
```

If you wish the run the code yourself, here is an arbitrary input: sierpinski([0 0], [1 0], [.5 .8], 2)
First picture below is what I get, second is what I want (apart from the black background). 
[image: What I get]

[image: What i want]

Comment: Can you add images of your current ouptut & expected output so that it's a bit clearer?

Comment: @BillBokeey Yes, check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is a recursive function, meaning that it will call itself again from its inner code, while `n>0` .

Now that this is set, let's try to understand what your code does and compare it to what you want your code to do.

**Step 1 :**

```
sierpinski([0 0], [1 0], [.5 .8], 0) ;
```

Here, as `n=0`, you won't evaluate the recursive calls.

**What your code does :**

a) Calculate the coordinates of the middles of the vertices constituting the input triangle

b) Draw the triangle corresponding to the input points

**What you want your code to do :**

a) Calculate the coordinates of the middles of the vertices constituting the input triangle

b) Draw the triangle corresponding to these MIDDLES.

**Step 2 :**

`sierpinski([0 0], [1 0], [.5 .8], 1) ;`

**What your code does :**

a) Calculate the middles of the vertices

b) Recursively call the function with the 3 outer triangles formed by picking 2 middles and 1 corresponding input point.

c) No plot

d)  The recursive calls will patch red the 3 outer triangles.

**You should be starting to see the problem. The only thing you need to do is :**

1) Move your call to patch outside of the `if` check so that it will be called everytime.

2) Change the inputs you pass to `patch` so that it plots the middles of the vertices of the input triangle.

So it's something along the lines of :

```
function out = sierpinski(a, b, c, n)
M1 = (a+b)/2;
M2 = (b+c)/2;
M3 = (a+c)/2;
k = [M1(1), M2(1), M3(1)];
m = [M1(2), M2(2), M3(2)];
patch(k,m,'r')  % choosing the color red in this case
if n==0
    out.x=[a(1), b(1), c(1)];
    out.y=[a(2), b(2), c(2)];
else
    s1 = sierpinski(a,M1,M3,n-1);
    s2 = sierpinski(M1,b,M2,n-1);
    s3 = sierpinski(M3,M2,c,n-1);
    out = [s1 s2 s3];
end
```

Comment: I tried with
`if n>=0  
    out.x=k;  
    out.y=m;  
    patch(out.x,out.y,'r')    
    pause(0.1)  `
But then it only patches for the largest n. How can I patch for all n without using for?

Comment: I'll edit my answer tomorrow, you have to understand how the recursive calls work

Comment: Thanks, now it is working as intended. But why is n=0 in step 1? Shouldn't it begin from n=n and end at n=0?

Comment: Oh the steps are just here to mean : "step i [in the understanding of the code] "

Comment: Just wanted to give a bit of informations about what happens for n=0 and n=1 so that you'd understand better